# how to send mail using handler?

Tags: email, handler

i want to send mail so i wrote one method in handler.ashx but i got error as

The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid. what does it mean pls help me

public bool Sendmail()
    {
        bool strResult = false;
        try
        {

```
        email.Subject = " Registration";

        email.To = "ravivarma_07d@yahoo.com";
        email.From = "giribhushan.svg@gmail.com";
        email.Cc = "ravivarma_07d@yahoo.com";
        email.Bcc = "ravivarma_07d@yahoo.com";
        email.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

        email.Body = "<html>" +
                       "<body>" +
                      "<b>Hi ravi</b>"+
                       "</body>" +
                       "</html>";
        email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;


       SmtpMail.Send(email);
        strResult = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //FTEHelper.SendEmail("ticketupload@whohastwo.com", "Ticket Upload Batch Error",
        //   ex.ToString());


        strResult = false;

    }


    return strResult;





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an SMTP server.

```
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "yourservername";
```

Also you should consider using System.Net.Mail namespace instead of System.Web.Mail. (If you aren't forced to use .NET 1, of course.)